# Using selenium rc java for checking json respose

Tags: selenium-rc

I want to test my json response using selenium rc (java) and to print all the response which has  garbage value

My json response is as follows :

```
{"date":"2012-03-02","data":[{"id":17,"Level":4,"Status":1},{"id":128,"Level":4,"Status":0},{"id":13,"Level":5,"Status":1},
```

So i would like to know how i can use selenium id to check the above mention scenario

Answer (score 1):

Well, some pointers to help you gt the answers..there was a captureNetworkTraffic flag in RC that needs to be set while starting selenium instance. Then use a selenium function to capture the traffic.  Then use a JSON library to parse the JSON and do string comparison for garbage value (depending on what you consider as garbage value :)  )

You can search for captureNetworkTraffic usage and then a json library for the language that you plan to use.